# Should user install .Net 4.5 Framework?

Tags: c#, .net

I am developing a WinForm application using .Net 4.5.

When a user install the software on their own computer, should they have .Net 4.5 Framework? Or will the software work without the user having the .Net 4.5 Framework? thanks

Comment: Yes. In the same way a Python script isn't going to work without Python installed, for instance.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, Client will need to install .NET Framework 4.5.**

There is .NET Framework Client Profile 4.0 which is smaller subset of Framework focused on client, but for Framework 4.5 has been discontinued.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - the user will need the .Net framework. But you can ensure they have it before your software is run (and they won't need to find/install it themselves) by chaining the installation of .Net 4.5 into your installer. See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942965(v=vs.110).aspx#chaining

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing for .Net 4.5 and it is not installed on the users pc then you program will not run. I would not develop for .Net 4.5 if you don't need a feature from .Net 4.5 as it is not supported in some OS.

I hope this is useful for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

your win applications needs .netframework which has been used in that to run, so it must be installed on user`s computer,
and about web application, it must be installed on web server only

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you design for .NET 4.5 the user will need .NET 4.5

When designing your app think about wheather you actually need .NET 4.5, can you use .NET 4 or .NET 3.5?

As Jaroslav Kubacek mentioned there is .NET 4 client framework but I would avoid this as in my experience it causes more problems then it solves (probably why it was discontinued)

When creating your installer you can set the .NET framework you need as prerequist/redistributables and either include the full installer or the download installer so that that the user is guided through installing .NET as part of your installation.

For InstallShield LE (free version):

- Specify Application Data > Redistributables.
- Check 'Microsoft .NET  Framework 4.5 Full'.
- Click No when prompted to download.
- Right click on'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 Full' > Properties
- Set Build location to 'Download'